# I couldn't find the definition of proc_create_data function in Linux kernel - or maybe I found it but failed to understand it

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

**Situation**

I'm following [this](https://lkw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/05_proc_interface.html) to better understand the Linux kernel.

There's an example on writing a custom /proc interface. Here's a snippet from the sample code linked above - `custom-proc.c`:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/types.h>

#omitted

int create_new_proc_entry(void) {
    int i;
    char *DATA = "Hello People";
    len = strlen(DATA);
    msg = kmalloc((size_t) DATA_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL); // +1 for \0

    if (msg != NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Allocated memory for msg");
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    strncpy(msg, DATA, len+1);
    for (i=0; i < len +1 ; i++) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%c", msg[i]);
        if (msg[i] == '\0') {
            printk(KERN_INFO "YES");
        }
    }
    proc = proc_create_data(MY_PROC_ENTRY, 0666, NULL, &proc_fops, msg);
    if (proc) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Since `proc_create_data` is not defined in the sample, I assume it must be defined somewhere in the kernel. I downloaded kernel 5x and search for all occurrence of `proc_create_data` in the kernel code and found that the only place where it was *defined* is in `/include/linux/proc_fs.h`:

```c
#Omitted

#define proc_create_data(name, mode, parent, proc_ops, data) ({ NULL; })

#Omitted

extern struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
                           struct proc_dir_entry *,
                           const struct proc_ops *, void *)
```

That's it.

I read from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros) that in C, macros will be textually expanded and one can use it like a function.

If I applied it here, then after all the expansion, I will have

`/include/linux/proc_fs.h`:

```c
#omitted
extern struct proc_dir_entry ({ NULL; })
```

`custom-proc.c`

```c
#omitted
proc = ({ NULL; })
```

Which doesn't seem right to me.

I'm not new to programming but not familiar with C. I read `The C programming Language` by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie but there explanation of macro is the same with the link above.

**Question (Main Course :))**

How do I understand the `proc_create_data` function as defined in the kernel?

I'm not looking for a very detail technical answer, just a way to interpret that code so I can follow along examples and be able to read more kernel code when needed by myself.

**Side Dish**
I heard somewhere that the kernel, despite being written in C, has some differences to "normal" C. I'm not sure if that's true or the extent of the discrepancy, however.

If this is a trick employed by "kernel version of the C language" it would be helpful if anyone knows a link to explanation of such tricks.

I've already looked around on following resources but couldn't find such info:

- [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org)
- https://kernelnewbies.org/
- Linux Kernel Development - Robert Love
- Linux System Programming - Robert Love

Comment: ? That `#Omitted` part is quite very important....

Comment: On a side note, how useful are the books by Robert Love today (or 3 years ago) considering they are old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this in [proc_fs.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.1/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L73):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_PROC_FS
extern struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
                           struct proc_dir_entry *,
                           const struct proc_ops *,
                           void *);
#else /* CONFIG_PROC_FS */
#define proc_create_data(name, mode, parent, proc_ops, data) ({NULL;})
#endif
```

If the user [configured kernel without proc filesystem support](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.1/source/fs/proc/Kconfig#L2), then the function call is expanded to a statement that just returns `NULL`. Note that  `({...})` is a [gcc extensions statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) - do not use non-portable extensions in your code and prefer using `static inline` functions. The return value of a statement expression is the value of the last expression used - `NULL` in this case.

If `CONFIG_PROC_FS` is defined from user configuration, then `proc/generic.c` defines the function [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.1/source/fs/proc/generic.c#L549) just like any other function, and source files including `proc_fs.h` see the function declaration and do not see the macro.

> I couldn't find the definition of proc_create_data function in Linux kernel

No worries - [typing `proc_create_data` in elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.1/A/ident/proc_create_data) results in all 3 definitions mentioned in this answer. There are even *multiple* indexed kernel source code browsers on the net, with [lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) as an example (but I see internal error right now on lxr). If not, you can index the source code on your computer with [ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) or [GNU GLOBAL](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) and browse the code then.

> How do I understand the proc_create_data function as defined in the kernel?

As any other function. No, the macro is not expanded with declaration - the compiler sees *either* the macro or the function declaration, depending if `PROC_FS` is enabled.

> Side Dish I heard somewhere that the kernel, despite being written in C, has some differences to "normal" C.

Linux kernel specifically targets GNU GCC compiler, so it tends to use [GNU C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), sometimes marked as GNU C.

Comment: I see you are editing so I don't want to mess up your post: you should link to line 102 for `proc_create_data` and also use `v5.9.1` instead of `latest` in the links otherwise they will break in the future.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. People like you are like wizards of the kernel land, without whom user land inhabitants like me couldn't venture into the kernel.